# Cannot instantiate the type GeoPoint Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to buid a simple app that when user enter his desired location its map appear.But i am getting an error Cannot instantiate the type GeoPoint i have also installed Google Play Services.
here is the code :

```
 public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

EditText location;
Geocoder geoCoder;
GeoPoint p;
MapController controller;
MapView mapView;
Button btnSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    location=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
     mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                             

        public void onClick(View arg0) {


    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(location.getText().toString(),1);
        if(addresses.size() > 0)
        {
             p = new GeoPoint( (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                              (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

               controller.animateTo(p);
               controller.setZoom(12);

               MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
             List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays(); 
                     listOfOverlays.clear();
             listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

               mapView.invalidate();
               location.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("Google Map");
                adb.setMessage("Please Provide the Proper Place");
                adb.setPositiveButton("Close",null);
                adb.show();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }
        });



}
```

Comment: do you have `import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;`

Comment: Can you show your error ?

Comment: imported that library but unable to launch my app.null launch cancel exception,i have tried many options like wipe user data,automatically 
choose target and reset abd.but nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you need to use v1 of the Google maps api, instead of the current v2?  If not, try using LatLng to store the location, and map.moveCamera(LatLng, float zoom) to go to the desired location as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).